# Irrational numbers and proving constant functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that for any irrational number $r$, and any real number $x$ we have $f(x)=f(x+r)$. Show that f is a constant function.

How would we go about solving this?  I have tried taking cases for $(x+r)$ being rational or irrational, but I am unable to prove either...

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: This is untrue if you mean only a single $r$.  Famously $\sin(x) = \sin(x+2\pi)$ and $2\pi$ is certainly irrational.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Just so you know, it is good practice on this site to tell us what you've tried so we can target answers to the area where you are confused or stuck. As the problem is stated, it's likely to be closed for not providing any context or attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: 1) Can you show that if $r$ is irrational, then $f(0) = f(r)$?

2) Once you've done that, suppose $q$ is a rational number. Let $r$ be any irrational. What can you say about $q-r$? Is it rational or irrational? Now, $f(q) = f((q-r)+r)$. Can you take it from there?